# ggplot to plot mean using geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, mean

Hello I would like to add mean values as points on a dot plot rather than the total count. I have 2 categorical factors: shore zone and depth. And a column for  count data, marked as either a 1 or 0 as presence of particles at a certain depths in a shore zone. Here is an example of what envisage the plot to look like.

```
## load ggplot
library(ggplot2)
## my own code for interest
szone.df <- ddply(transect.df, .(shore.zone, depth.cm), summarise, count = sum(count))
summary(szone.df)

## reproducible data
shorezone <- c("HWM","HWM","HWM","HWM","IT","IT","IT","IT","ST","ST","ST","ST")
depth <- c("50","25", "10", "0","50","25","10", "0","50","25","10","0")
count <- c(0, 1, 9, 232, 0 ,27, 0, 15, 0, 1, 0, 8)

## create data frame
szone <- data.frame(shorezone, depth, count)
szone
## depth to factor
szone$depth <- as.factor(szone$depth)
## reverse factor 
szone$depth = with(szone, factor(depth, levels = rev(levels(depth))))

## plot data that I would like the grpah to look like but with mean values
s.zone <- ggplot(szone) + aes(x = shorezone, y = depth, size = count) +
geom_point() +
scale_size_area(name = "Count", max_size = 45) + 
theme(legend.title = element_text(colour = "black", size = 20, face = "bold"), 
    legend.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = 18),
    axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 22, face = "bold", margin = margin(15,0,0,0)),
    axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 22, face = "bold", margin = margin(0,15,0,0)),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = "18"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = "18"), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey")) +
scale_fill_grey(start = 0.1, end = 0.6) +
scale_x_discrete(name = "Shore Zone")+
scale_y_discrete(name = "Depth (cm)")
s.zone
```

However following the above code I extracted and summed the count data beforehand using ddply. When using my original data frame ggplot plots the count data as either 1 or 0. If I add size = count it returns the frequency of 0's in the data set (attached photos). Here is the code without summing before hand:

```
szone <- ggplot(transect.df, aes(x = shorezone, y = depth, size = count)) +
geom_count() +
scale_size_area() +
theme(legend.title = element_text(colour = "black", size = 20, face = "bold"), 
    legend.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = 18),
    axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 22, face = "bold", margin = margin(15,0,0,0)),
    axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 22, face = "bold", margin = margin(0,15,0,0)),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = "18"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = "18"), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey")) + 
scale_fill_grey(start = 0.1, end = 0.6) +
scale_x_discrete(name = "Shore Zone") +
scale_y_discrete(name = "Depth (cm)")
szone
```

I've read that ggplot can deal with plotting sums & means without playing round/aggregating the original data set. I've spent all day going in circles so apologies if this is not clear, R has taken its toll on me.

I'm looking to plot the data without summing count data beforehand so I can generate and plot mean values using ggplot functions. Count data is no. of particles found at certain depth within a shore zone. + I would like to find the mean no of particles for each shore zones at different depths and plot using a ggplot function. Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[image: plotted 50 values but data is 0]
[[image: count 1 & 0]]

Comment: While it is sometimes possible to have `ggplot` aggregate data for you in certain ways, usually I find the most expedient solution is to just transform the data outside of ggplot.